# How to call java file from different directory using nodejs child process

Tags: java, node.js, classpath, child-process, spawn

I am trying to run a java class file from a different directory. However, it always gives the error "*Could not find or load main class {dirpath}*"

My project directory is as follows:

```
  - NodeProject
    - code
      - Main.java
      - javaClasses
    - index.js
```

"code" folder contains java src files, that I take as input from a candidate/user and save it as *filename*.java and a folder "javaClasses", which should contain the .class file after compilation. 
 index.js is my entry point which runs via *npm start*

my index.js code is as follows:

```
const spawnSync = require("child_process").spawnSync;
const { exec } = require("child_process")
const path = require('path');


let filepath = path.join(__dirname, "code", "Main.java");
let dirpath = path.join(__dirname, "code", "javaClasses");
let folderPath = path.join(__dirname, "code");

const run = async (command, args) => {
    let options = "";


    let output = spawnSync("javac", ["-d", dirpath, filepath]); /// creates Main.class file in javaClasses folder

    exec(`${command} "${args}" | java -cp ${dirpath} Main`, (error, stdout, stderr) =>{
      if (error) {
          console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
          return;
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
      });

    
    
    
}

let s ="22"
run("printf", [s]);
```

.class file is succesfully compiled, exec command is giving the error. 
 I tried replacing *dirpath* with *folderpath* where the actual src file is but to no avail. 
 I saw somewhere to try *cd {path} & java Main* but it still doesn't work and give the same error.

Also, my src file doesn't have any package import like *package code*, since i take the whole src file from user input.

Any help will be very much appreciated!.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understood your problem correctly, but i will give it a try.

If the contents of Main.java looks like this:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
 }
```

I don't have any Problem just running this with the code you provided.

The Problem starts if i modify the Main.java to look like this:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        Echoer e = new Echoer();
        e.setReq("Hello world!");
        System.out.println(e.getRes());
    }
 }
```

Echoer.java:

```java
public class Echoer {
    private String req = null;
    private String res = null;
    public void setReq(String r) {
       req = new String(r);
       char[] a = r.toCharArray();
       int n = a.length;
       for (int i=0; i<n/2; i++) {
          char t = a[i];
          a[i] = a[n-1-i];
          a[n-i-1] = t;
       }
       res = new String(a);
    }
    public String getRes() {
       return res;
    }
 }
```

I do get the Error "Could not find or load main class Main", which should be equal to your provided message as dirpath is set to

```js
let filepath = path.join(__dirname, "code", "Main.java");
```

I assume you want to call some Methods in your Main.java which are defined in another Java File. To achieve this, we need to tell the Java Compiler to compile any Java Files present. I modified the index.js file to look like this

```js
const spawnSync = require("child_process").spawnSync;
const { exec } = require("child_process")
const path = require('path');


let filepath = path.join(__dirname, "code", "*.java");
let dirpath = path.join(__dirname, "code", "javaClasses");
let folderPath = path.join(__dirname, "code");

const run = async (command, args) => {


    let options = "";


    exec(`javac -d ${dirpath} ${filepath}`, (error, stdout, stderr) =>{
        if (error) {
            console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
            return;
          }
          console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
          console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
          exec(`${command} "${args}" | java -cp ${dirpath} Main`, (error, stdout, stderr) =>{
            if (error) {
                console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
                return;
              }
              console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
              console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            });
        });
}

let s ="22"
run("printf", [s]);
```

This now works with as many .java Files as you like.

Note 1: I did delete the .class Files after every run

Note 2: I did not get it to work with spawnSync

Comment: Hi!, thank you for the answer. Actually my code doesn't work even for simple print statements like "Hello World". It gives the same error *Could not find or load main classuser/../NodeProject/code/javaClasses*.

I tried with your solution, but now it gives the error *command failed: javac -d {dirpath} {filepath}, error: invalid flag {dirpath}*.
What i am actually doing, i only need to compile specific files, that i control via filename, and the java src file won't import from any other class, but it will contain Scanner/buffer reader method to take in user input. Hence i was using "printf".

Comment: That seems weird, your code worked for me first try with a simple "Hello World" Java File.

Does it work when you do it manually in a Terminal? If not, i would believe the problem is somewhere in your Environment or your Java Files, not the JavaScript Code.
I had a Problem, that my CodeEditor would sometimes just add "package code" to my Java Files, then the error would occur. Maybe you do have the same issue?


My "npm start" is a simple "node index.js". Node Version: 14.18.1

Comment: Yup, even I don't why it didn't worked even for a simple "Hello World". I tried to run it manually from a terminal by first moving into the code directory and it worked well. Just couldn't make it work with my code.

Comment: This is how i solved this issue though, I changed my exec() command to `exec(${command} ${args} | java Main, {cwd : dirpath} , (error, stdout, stdin) => {console.log(stdout)})`  now it works as expected.
Thank you for the help!